# Animating two images in java

Tags: java, swing, object, animation, keylistener

I'm quite new to java. I need to animate two images on a java game. It's meant to be a spaceship game allowing two users to control the objects, using a keyboard. I've partially implemented this, however I cannot understand how to allow for two keyboard controls, and also the one object that is moving via keyboard input is flickering a lot.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    MainPanel mPanel;
        MainPanel secondss;
         MainPanel thirdss;
        int speed = 5;
        //ss facing north
        int direction = 0;

    MainFrame() {
        setTitle("spaceship Game");
        mPanel = new MainPanel("C:/img");
                secondss = new MainPanel("C:/img");

        setSize(1024, 768);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(mPanel); // add MainPanel JPanel to JFrame
        setVisible(true); // show class

                add(secondSs);
                add(thirdSs);
                seconds.currentSs.setX(400);
                secondSS.currentSs.setY(100);
    }

   public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
   {
     if( e.getSource() == mPanel)
     {
     }
   }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_LEFT) {

         int x = mPanel.currentSs.getX() - speed;
         mPanel.currentSs.setX(x);
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_RIGHT) {
         int x = mPanel.currentSs.getX() + speed;
         mPanel.currentSs.setX(x);
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_DOWN) {
         int y = mPanel.currentSs.getY() + speed;
         mPanel.currentSs.setY(y);
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_UP) {
         int y = mPanel.currentSs.getY() - speed;
         mPanel.currentSs.setY(y);
        }
        //change image direction    
        mPanel.frame = direction;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
                mainFrame.addKeyListener(mainFrame);
    }
```

If someone could provide help or if not point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: use `paint(Graphics g)`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.  @KlemensMorbe  For at least two reasons, it is better **not** to paint directly to a top level container but instead use a `JPanel` to do painting in.

Answer (score 4):

- JFrame isn't focusable for KeyEvents, then by default never to react to KeyEvents
- setVisible(true); should be last code line, after all JComponents are added to JFrame,
- for why reason is there public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ), must generating excpetion form compilier

---

- create a JFrame as local variable
- put JPanel into JFrame
- override getPreferredSize for JPanel, instesad of setSize for JFrame
- then call pack() and setVisble(true)

---

- put images to the Java package
- put Images to JLabel
- set NullLayout to JPanel (otherwise animations isn't possible)
- add KeyBindings to JPanel, override desired/required KeyEvents

---

- there is another way by using Custom painting, by override paintComponent for JPanel, for KeyEvents stays here KeyBindings as better listener in compare with KeyListener

Comment: *"for why reason is there public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ), must generating excpetion form compilier"* Huh?  If it used `@Override` notation (which is best) it would produce a compiler error, but why would the code shown produce a compiler error?  +1 for the rest of your many good tips.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson  but why would the code shown produce a compiler error? - because isn't there implements ActionListener, so far I can see

Comment: If the code had `implements ActionListener` **without** `actionPerformed(..)` I could understand a compilation error.  **Or** if the `actionPerformed(..)` had declared `@Override`. But as it was, without both `implements ActionListener` **and** `@Override` it should compile cleanly.  Unfortunately, it is not compilable for a lot of other reasons, (missing classes, unclosed `{`..) so I am unable to easily check what I'm saying here.. ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson s.o.s, not or yes, I don't know

Comment: AFAIU no (shrugs), but that is as far as I'm willing to speculate/guess short of seeing an SSCCE from the OP.

Answer (score 3):

> It's meant to be a spaceship game allowing two users to control the objects, using a keyboard

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings.

See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and examples.

The `KeyboardAnimation` example demonstrates how two users can control individual images.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a lot you should change here:

1. Graphics in games is seldom done using components. Remember that components carry a lot of weight with them (e.g. UI delegate, listeners, peer, etc.). What you should do is to create a single custom component which will act as a game board. This component's paint methods will paint to images of spaceships. This will also get rid of the flickering (invoke `setDoubleBuffered(true)` on that component)
2. The location of the ships should be changed independently of the painting, i.e. the location should be calculated and kept in member variables, and the painting should happen according to swing's painting manager's will. However, you can still enforce more rigorous painting by using `paintImmediately(...)` to paint the images of the ships whenever they move
3. There's no way (at least not that I'm aware of) to handle two keyboards or anything of the kind. If you want 2 users playing at once, they should use the same keyboard, and you should have 2 separate (and hopefully distant) sets of keys, one for each player. Just like in the old days :-)

Comment: `However, you can still enforce more rigorous painting by using paintImmediately(...) to paint the images of the ships whenever they move` == but you would need to be nesure that this painting is of out EDT, otherwise RepaintManager can kill current JVM, :-)

Comment: `invoke setDoubleBuffered(true)`, Swing is double buffered by default.

Answer (score 0):

From how I understand the question, the players need to interact with the game using different sets of keys depending on you are player 1 or player 2. If that's the case, implement the KeyListener and override the following methods just like what the following codes does:

```
@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
            playerOne_up = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
            playerOne_down = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            playerTwo_up = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            playerTwo_down = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
            playerOne_up = false;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
            playerOne_down = false;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            playerTwo_up = false;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            playerTwo_down = false;

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            if (!isStarted()) {
                doInitializations();
                setStarted(true);
            }
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            if (isStarted()) {
                setStarted(false);
            } else {
                frame.dispose();
            }

                }

        }
```

However, in my example, only movements up and down are allowed (pingpong game). Player one uses W for up and S for down while Player two uses UP arrow key and DOWN arrow key. The booleans playerOne_up, playerOne_down, etc are the switches for other methods to see if the object needs to be moved on which direction.